# White background on font icon on copying, but blue in text

Tags: html, css

When I try to copy the text along with font icons, the background changes to blue, but the background of the icons remains white. It feels like I'm not selecting the icons. How do I change the icon background color on copying?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Can you provide some code to show how the icons are implemented?

Comment: What are the icons? Hard to help when we do not have that info.

Comment: Essentially, the icon has a white background where the font has a transparent background. You can try to change the background colour on the element to see if the icon still has white background. If you use this same font, then there isn't much you can do

Comment: Purpose:Combination of text and icons(used ionicons) to be selected and change the color of it.  Issue: when we try to copy(drag the mouse for section) the text and icons, by default background blue color is applied for the text but not on icons. We dont know whether icons got selected or not. Simply, Selection is not happening for icon, showing white background.

Answer (score 0):

The background of the icons *is* being selected, and it *is* blue. The issue is that your icons have opaque backgrounds themselves, which obscures the blue selection indicator.

Unless the icons are SVG and you can modify their properties with CSS, you can't change this. Even then I'm not sure that the `:selected` property applies for that type of selection.